# Prove subset of Field is a subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K$ be a ﬁeld of characteristic different from 2, $F$ an algebraic extension of $K$ and $L$ a
subset of $F$ with the following properties: $L$ contains $K$, $L$ is a K-vector space, $\forall v \in L, $
and all positive integers $n$, $v^n \in L$. Prove that L is a subﬁeld of F.

Since $K$ is a field, and $K$ is contained in L, we have $1 \in K, 0 \in K \rightarrow 1\in L.
 0 \in L$

From the answer below, I know that since L is a vector space, it is an abelian group under addition.
Hence all that remains is to show L is an abelian group under multiplication.

How can I utilize

F an algebraic extension of K.  (Every element of F, satisfies some nonzero polynomial $\in K[x]$

characteristic of K play a role?

to show L is closed under multiplication?

Comment: It is a mystery to me where $v*v^{n-1}=1$ comes from. And your main task is to show that $L$ is closed under multiplication (and inverses); I don't think you did anything towards that goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closure of$~L$ under multiplication follows in characteristic${}\neq2$ from additive closure and closure under squaring: $xy=\frac12((x+y)^2-x^2-y^2)$. Closure of$~L$ under inverses of nonzero elements follows from the fact that $K/F$ is algebraic: every $x\in L$ satisfies a polynomial equation, that we can assume with nonzero constant term by dividing out a power of$~x$, say $a_nx^n +\cdots+a_1x+a_0 =0$ with $a_0\neq0$. Isolating $a_0$ and factoring $x$ out of the rest gives $x(a_nx^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1)=-a_0$, so we get a polynomial $-a_0^{-1}(a_nx^{n-1}+\cdots+a_1)$ in$~x$ that is the inverse of$~x$, and it lies in$~L$ by the preceding point.

Comment: I'm sorry for my stupidity >.<  abstract algebra is hard. You if $f(x) \in K[x]$ is the minimal polynomial of $x \in L$  say $f(x) = a_nx^n +....+a_1x+a_0 =0$ Following your steps: 1) dividing out by a power of x $\rightarrow$ $ a_nx^{n-1} + ...+a_1 + (1/x)a_0 =0$

Comment: 2)isolating this(what does "this" refer to?) constant term: $ a_1 + a_nx^{n-1} +....+(1/x)a_0 =0$

Comment: 3) factoring x out of the rest: $ a_1 + x( x^{n-2} +....+ \dfrac{1}{x^2}a_0) =0$

Comment: I think I did it wrong, will this alternative work?

Comment: Nevermind :'(, I was doing it all wrong

Comment: @abe15: I've detailed the construction.

Answer (score 2):

"$L$ is a $K$-vector space" means that $L$ is an abelian group under addition i.e. you can add and subtract members of $L$ and stay in $L$, and that you can multiply elements of $L$ by elements of $K$ (the $K$ elements are thought of as scalars). Multiplication by scalars satisfies the associative law. The addition within $L$ combined with multiplication by scalars obeys the distributive law.

In short, everything works nicely as you would expect.

Comment: Does the assumption that the characteristic of K is not 2 matter? BTW Thanks! :D

Comment: How do you argue that $L$ is closed under multiplication?